# Spring security не переключается между http/https

Tags: spring, https, spring-security

Пытаюсь настроить https в приложении. Вроде всё сделал по документации и туториалам, но всё равно приложение разворачивается по умолчанию как http.

security-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

   <security:http pattern="mvcresources/css/**" security="none" />
   <security:http pattern="mvcresources/js/**" security="none" />

   <security:http auto-config="true">
          <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*" access="ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="https" />
       <security:intercept-url pattern="/login/*" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="https" />
       <security:intercept-url pattern="**/**" access="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" requires-channel="https" />

          <security:form-login login-page="/login"
                               default-target-url="/welcome"
                               authentication-failure-url="/failure"/>
          <security:logout logout-success-url="/login"/>
       <security:port-mappings>
           <!-- Default ports -->
           <security:port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
           <!-- Websphere default ports -->
           <security:port-mapping http="9080" https="9443"/>
           <!-- Tomcat default ports -->
           <security:port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
           <!-- Jetty custom ports -->
           <security:port-mapping http="7777" https="7443"/>
       </security:port-mappings>
    </security:http>

   <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
          <security:authentication-provider>
                 <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" />
          </security:authentication-provider>
   </security:authentication-manager>

   <bean id="userDetailsService"
         class="org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager">
          <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
          <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
          <property name="enableAuthorities" value="true"/>
   </bean>

   <bean id="passwordEncoder"
         class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="***" />
    <property name="username" value="***" />
    <property name="password" value="***" />
</bean>
```

Если руками ввести https:// то всё работает конечно.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
     http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.***</groupId>
<artifactId>****</artifactId>
<version>${project.version}</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</project.version>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring.mvc>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.mvc>
    <spring.security>3.2.8.RELEASE</spring.security>
    <spring.data>1.3.4.RELEASE</spring.data>
    <javax.servlet>3.0.1</javax.servlet>
    <mysql.version>5.1.40</mysql.version>
    <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
    <mchange.version>0.2.12</mchange.version>
    <spring.test>3.2.4.RELEASE</spring.test>
    <javax.mail.version>1.4.7</javax.mail.version>
    <mail.version>1.5.5</mail.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2.1</jstl.version>
    <jsp.version>2.2</jsp.version>
    <json.version>2.2.4</json.version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <logback.version>1.1.3</logback.version>
    <jcl.slf4j.version>1.7.12</jcl.slf4j.version>
    <jackson.version>1.9.10</jackson.version>
    <freemarker.version>2.3.26-incubating</freemarker.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.mvc}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.data}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.test}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.servlet}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mysql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
        <version>${mchange.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP-java7</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-hikaricp</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>smtp</artifactId>
        <version>${mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>${mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
        <version>${mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
        <version>${mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>taglibs-standard-jstlel</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsp.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>${json.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>${logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Apache FreeMarker -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
        <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
        <version>${freemarker.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jsoup -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.2</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>survey-${project.version}</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А какой результат вы ожидаете?

Comment: Что при старте приложение будет запускаться через https

Comment: вы используете встроенный сервер или внешний? какой?

Comment: локальный - tomcat 8. Вообще приложение деплоится на Амазон.
SSL локально настраивал. И на Амазоне также имеется подписанный сертификат и настроен load balancer.

Comment: тогда смотрите настройки сервера, так приложение не может изменить порт или протокол